# Recursion in factorial function

Tags: objective-c, recursion

Feeling stupid, but I really can't understand that.

On the code below, why does the recursion in the `else if` statement stops when it reaches 1? Shouldn't it return -1 eventually and keep returning it to infinity?

```
- (int)factorial:(int)operand
{
    if      (operand < 0) return -1;
    else if (operand > 1) return operand * [self factorial:operand - 1];
    else                  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see this in steps.

```
[self factorial:3]

return 3 * [self factorial:2];

return 3 * (2 * [self factorial:1]);

return 3 * (2 * (1 * [self factorial:0]));

return 3 * (2 * (1 * (1))) // Reached to return 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

So recursion just calls the method again and again till you reach some sort of base case. Let's see what happens if `operand` equals one:

```
if      (operand < 0) return -1;
```

It is not less than zero so continue to the next clause.

```
else if (operand > 1) return operand * [self factorial:operand - 1];
```

It is not > 1 it is equal to 1 so go to the next clause.

```
else                  return 1;
```

This is what it has to be, so it returns 1.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know it's a basic question, so thanks for taking the time to answer it. I accepted the answer by @scha just because to me it was clearer.